# Unable to show category wise data in sections of home page

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to fetch category wise data in home page's sections but I am unable to do this. Only one category section is working[enter image description here][1]

I made Section model and under this model Category model My IndexController Code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Front;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Slider;
use App\Category;
use App\Section;

    class IndexController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(){
            $sliders = Slider::where('status',1)->get();
            $categories = Category::with('sections')->where('status',1)->get();
            //dd($categories);die;
            return view('frontend.index')->with(compact('sliders','categories'));
        }
    }
```

and blade file code is :

```
<section class="latest_work">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row sub_content">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="dividerHeading">
                        <h4><span>Find your best tours</span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="recent-work-slider" class="owl-carousel">
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                        @if($category['sections']['section_name'] == "Tours")
                        <div class="product">
                            <figure class="touching effect-bubba">
                                <div class="product-img">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('images/categories/'.$category['category_banner']) }}">
                                    <div class="option">
                                        <a class="fa fa-shopping-cart" href="portfolio_single.html"></a>
                                        <a class="fa fa-search mfp-image" href="{{ asset('images/categories/'.$category['category_banner']) }}"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="product-info">
                                <div class="product-title">
                                    <h3>
                                        <a href="#">{{ $category['category_name'] }}</a>
                                    </h3>
                                </div><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="latest_work">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row sub_content">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="dividerHeading">
                        <h4><span>Find your best stays</span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="recent-work-slider" class="owl-carousel">
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                        @if($category['sections']['section_name'] == "Stays")
                        <div class="product">
                            <figure class="touching effect-bubba">
                                <div class="product-img">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('images/categories/'.$category['category_banner']) }}">
                                    <div class="option">
                                        <a class="fa fa-shopping-cart" href="portfolio_single.html"></a>
                                        <a class="fa fa-search mfp-image" href="{{ asset('images/categories/'.$category['category_banner']) }}"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="product-info">
                                <div class="product-title">
                                    <h3>
                                        <a href="#">{{ $category['category_name'] }}</a>
                                    </h3>
                                </div><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="latest_work">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row sub_content">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="dividerHeading">
                        <h4><span>Find your best cars</span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="recent-work-slider" class="owl-carousel">
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                        @if($category['sections']['section_name'] == "Cars")
                        <div class="product">
                            <figure class="touching effect-bubba">
                                <div class="product-img">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('images/categories/'.$category['category_banner']) }}">
                                    <div class="option">
                                        <a class="fa fa-shopping-cart" href="portfolio_single.html"></a>
                                        <a class="fa fa-search mfp-image" href="{{ asset('images/categories/'.$category['category_banner']) }}"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="product-info">
                                <div class="product-title">
                                    <h3>
                                        <a href="#">{{ $category['category_name'] }}</a>
                                    </h3>
                                </div><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

only one tours section's categories is showing but not showing other categories

Comment: Please include the code directly in your question.

Comment: please do not put up images of code, code is text, add it to your question as text in a code block

Comment: Only tours section's categories are showing

Answer (score 0):

Yes Only one tour sections is showing because of this condition in your code

```
 @if($category['sections']['section_name'] == "Tours")
........................
@endif
```